# Parsing Text Streamed Log With Split on Index

Tags: javascript, parsing, split

I have log files that are just raw text saved. I have no control how these log files were written. They are saved how the data was streamed. I am trying to parse it out where each line begins with an index.

Log files and expected output is below. The log files always begin with an index of 13 digits (likely padded) so I take that as the index. I then split the content with the index to get the first initial lines working. I then put this in a while loop checking whether the file was able to split anything with `lines.length > 1`.

I noticed that I used split incorrectly as it is only for finding the line endings and not where they begin. Otherwise it would work with the expected result. With that said, is there an easy fix for this partial solution I have?

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var output = [];

reader.readAsText(f, "UTF-8");

            // if file read successful then text string stored in the result property of FileReader()
            reader.onload = function(evt){
                var fileContents = evt.target.result;
                var index = fileContents.slice(0,13);
                var lines = fileContents.split(index);

                // Continue splitting until we fail (nothing split = 1)
                //while(lines.length > 1){
                    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
                        output.push(index + ' ' + lines[i] + '<br>')
                    }

                    // go to next lines
                    index++;
                    lines = fileContents.split(index);
                //}

                document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
            }
```

Provided log file:

```
1564001512016 INFO: LOG MANAGER jdshfkjaafhdskfdsajfdsadsfj 1564001512016 INFO: some test stuff 1564001512016 INFO: kjhdshfakhfdskjdshkjfdsh 1564001512017 INFO: hjkdsahfjkfhdskjfdsahkfdskjfdsakjfds 1564001512017 INFO: hdskjahfjfdshdfsahfdsajfdsa
```

Actual output:

```
1564001512016 INFO: LOG MANAGER jdshfkjaafhdskfdsajfdsadsfj
1564001512016 INFO: some test stuff 
1564001512016 INFO: kjhdshfakhfdskjdshkjfdsh 1564001512017 INFO: hjkdsahfjkfhdskjfdsahkfdskjfdsakjfds 1564001512017 INFO: hdskjahfjfdshdfsahfdsajfdsa
```

Expected Output:

```
1564001512016 INFO: LOG MANAGER jdshfkjaafhdskfdsajfdsadsfj 
1564001512016 INFO: some test stuff
1564001512016 INFO: kjhdshfakhfdskjdshkjfdsh 
1564001512017 INFO: hjkdsahfjkfhdskjfdsahkfdskjfdsakjfds 
1564001512017 INFO: hdskjahfjfdshdfsahfdsajfdsa
```

**Update**:
With the answer below I was able to tailor it to my code below. Some notable changes adding back the `INFO` string that was removed by split (for some reason) and storing int `i` into a variable `x` to not increment a 3rd at each iteration:

```
                var fileContents = evt.target.result;
                var regex = /(\d{13}) INFO:/
                var lines = fileContents.split(regex);

                // i starts at 1 as split seems to always return empty at 0
                for(var i = 1; i < lines.length; i+=2){
                    var x = i;
                    var index = lines[x]
                    var context = lines[x+1]
                    // \xa0 = space
                    output.push('<li>' + index + "\xa0INFO:\xa0\xa0" + context + '</li>')
                }
                document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = output.join('') + '</br>';
```

Result:

```
1564001512016 INFO:  LOG MANAGER jdshfkjaafhdskfdsajfdsadsfj 
1564001512016 INFO:  some test stuff
1564001512016 INFO:  kjhdshfakhfdskjdshkjfdsh 
1564001512017 INFO:  hjkdsahfjkfhdskjfdsahkfdskjfdsakjfds 
1564001512017 INFO:  hdskjahfjfdshdfsahfdsajfdsa
```

Comment: There is no reliable way to parse this file.  You could come close with a regex, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the index changes periodically, there are no line endings, and the log message could contain arbitrary text, there is no reliable way to parse this file.  You can come close with regular expressions, however:

```
var regex = /(\d{13}) INFO:/
var lines = fileContents.split(regex);

for(var i = 1; i < lines.length; i+=2){
    var index = lines[i];
    var line = lines[i+1];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Great! The regex helped a lot! I made some edits. Split removed the INFO portion, so I added it back followed by 2 spaces to match the formatting. Also doing `regex = /(\d{13}) INFO:/` ensures its not some arbirary 13 digits so looking for the INFO afterwards gives integrity to the parsing. I also stored the local variable `x`so that `i` wouldnt increment an extra step at each interval. (Full solution in my post" but I am accepting this as the answer as it led to my tailored solution.

Comment: @Minutia Using `i+1` won't increment it an additional step.  If `i` is 1, then `i+1` is 2, but `i` is still 1 afterward (the `+` operator doesn't modify anything).